# Firefox keeps crashing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox

Since yesterday, every time I visit Youtube Firefox crashes. Also, it crashes on some other video streaming sites (or pages that include a video player like jwplayer for example), but not every time.

I have started Firefox in save mode, and also reinstalled it. I also uninstalled flash player - still crashing (Note that I use Youtube's HTML5-player as standard).

I can't find any solution on the internet. Maybe somebody has some ideas to fix Firefox? I can't even guess what could be the reason for those crashes.

Bug report from firefox:

```
BuildID: 20150112203352
CrashTime: 1421759307
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1421326467
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile  -- 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 15
StartupTime: 1421759297
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 35.0
useragent_locale: chrome://global/locale/intl.properties

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment since it might be argued that it isn't exactly an answer.  Lately, my experiences with BOTH FF and GC have been sooo bad that I have them both loaded and use them both concurrently so that I'm slightly less annoyed when one freezes or drops out.  I don't blame ubuntu.  I'm not sure what's causing this.  Oh and last week I actually opened Opera at one point.

Comment: @gyropyge Yes, it's really strange. I don't blame Ubuntu either, in fact I don't know who to blame (Mozille maybe?). Anyway, I will use Chrome for pages that don't work in FF currently, and hope it will be fixed soon or someone has a solution.

Comment: actually I think I may know what this is.  I've noticed that seemingly every time there's a big hack, such as the recent sony thing, or the discovery of a BASH bug, everything goes crazy for a few weeks as sysadmins try to fix everything.  My guess is that the fault lies neither in FF or GC but rather that all the sites are suddenly slightly incompatible with the expectations of the web browsers.

Comment: Well, that's a valid point. However, for me only Firefox doesn't work. My brother, using same Ubuntu and Firefox versions, doesn't have this problem (like no one else, except me). I think it should be something more specific.

Comment: I hate to have to say this, but given the limited information, I'll assume that your real problem stems from using 14.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If somebody is interested in the solution, here it is:

I don't know why but some parts of streamer seemed to be missing on my system. I am sure that neither Ubuntu nor Firefox were updated right before the crashes began, so I can't tell the actual reason why the bug occured.

However, solution was quite simple:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-*
```

Downloads and installs a bunch of gstreamer libraries, now everything works fine again.

Comment: I also needed to restart my computer after installing the gstreamer libraries.

Comment: There must be a neater way than installing everything related to `gstreamer1.0`

Comment: I got mine fixed by following the link [link](http://fcorti.com/2014/04/22/ffmpeg-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)   

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg `

Comment: Can someone please explain why gstreamer is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

you need to reinstall Microsoft true type core fonts and adobe flash player both.first remove ttf-mscorefonts installer as

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and accept Microsoft's license using tab key then reinstall adobe flash player

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

then firefox  will not crash.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but didn't work. FF still broken.

Comment: When reinstalling on 14.04. I ran into the following error message:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] timed out
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) ...
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu1) ...